# Hashing with Linked Lists

Tags: java, hash, linked-list

I am trying to do a form of coalesced hashing, and to do so, I need to maintain multiple linked lists that get created when you try to insert something into the table and it collides with another object. How would I go about creating multiple linked lists inside of an add(object x) function and then be able to call the same list again in a find(object x) function?

For example, if my hash value is 5, and bucket 5 is occupied, I create a linked list with bucket 5 as a head, and then create a new node where the object I tried to put into 5 ends up getting put. This way when I try to find the object latter, rather than probe the table, I can just follow the linked list I created referencing slot 5 and follow it to my object.

My issue is, I can not figure out how to maintain multiple linked lists for different collisions, and then call the appropriate list later on when I try to find the object. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In short, you're reinventing HashMap, right? The source code is available. You can read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to replicate something like `HashMap` (and it sounds very much like you are), you'll want to keep the linked lists in search tree, so that you can find the right list for inserting **and** for finding an object in reasonable time.